Vite, Tailwind & PostCSS build message and broken CSS
I am currently working on a project that is built using Vite & Tailwind and I am getting the following build message:

A PostCSS plugin did not pass the from option to postcss.parse.
This may cause imported assets to be incorrectly transformed. If
you've recently added a PostCSS plugin that raised this warning,
please contact the package author to fix the issue.

These are my dependencies:
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "vite": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/nesting": "^0.0.0-insiders.565cd3e",
    "alpinejs": "^3.12.0",
    "gsap": "^3.11.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "plyr": "^3.7.3",
    "swiper": "^11.1.1",
    "tailwindcss-animated": "^1.0.1"
  }

tailwind.config.js:
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
const palette = require("./assets/color-palette.json");
const colorNames = Object.keys(palette);
const safelistPattern = new RegExp(`bg-(${colorNames.join('|')})\/(10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|90|100)`);

module.exports = {
    content: [
        // By default, use our 'src' and 'views' directories
        "./assets/src/css/**/*.css",
        "./assets/src/js/**/*.js",
        "./views/**/*.twig"
    ],
    safelist: [
        {
            pattern: safelistPattern,
        }
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
          
            gridTemplateColumns: {
                '14': 'repeat(14, minmax(0, 1fr))',
                '16': 'repeat(16, minmax(0, 1fr))',
            },
            gridColumn: {
                'span-13': 'span 13 / span 13',
                'span-14': 'span 14 / span 14',
            }, 
            keyframes: {
                jellohorizontal: {
                    '0%':{ transform:'scale3d(1,1,1)'},
                    '30%':{transform:'scale3d(1.25,.75,1)'},
                    '40%':{transform:'scale3d(.75,1.25,1)'},
                    '50%':{transform:'scale3d(1.15,.85,1)'},
                    '65%':{transform:'scale3d(.95,1.05,1)'},
                    '75%':{transform:'scale3d(1.05,.95,1)'},
                    '100%':{transform:'scale3d(1,1,1)'}
                },
            },
            animation: {
                'jello-horizontal': 'jellohorizontal .9s both',
            },
            screens: {
                'xsm': '481px',
                'mdlg': '980px',
                '3xl': '1744px'
            },
            spacing : {
                '12.5' : '3.125rem', //50px
                '15': '3.75rem',
            },
            colors: {
                ...palette
            },
            fontFamily: {
                'serif': ['Ivar', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif],
                'sans': ['Inter', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            typography: {
                quoteless: {
                  css: {
                    'blockquote p:first-of-type::before': { content: 'none' },
                    'blockquote p:first-of-type::after': { content: 'none' },
                  },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    corePlugins: {
        aspectRatio: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-import"),
        require("tailwindcss/nesting"),
        require("@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio"),
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp"),
        require("@tailwindcss/typography")
    ],
};

postcss.config.js:
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}

I tried removing the postcss-nested plugin and uninstalling it but that did not work. I also tried deleting nested rules throughout the stylesheets but that did not seems to work.
Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in the front end: It seems like TW is adding before and after pseudo selectors to all divs, which causes css issues throughout my project
I am somewhat stuck on this issue for a couple of days now and running out of things to try.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
UPDATE
I found that this bit of code introduced the build message:
div.full-width-image-hero + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding), 
div.product-hero + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.team-member-hero + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.contact-hero + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding) {
    /* heroes should only have padding below if the next block has a white bg */
    @apply pt-12 md:pt-24
}

div.bg-dark-blue + div.bg-dark-blue, 
div.bg-white + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.bg-warm-ivory + div.bg-warm-ivory {
    @apply pt-0;
}

div.bg-dark-blue + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding), 
div.bg-warm-ivory + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.full-width-cta + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.fifty-fifty + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding),
div.pin-spacer + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding) {
    @apply pt-12 md:pt-24
}

div.py-9 + div.bg-white:not(.preserve-padding) {
    @apply pt-3 md:pt-15
}

Can you not use the @apply rule on it's own? What am I missing here?

I replicated a project with your code on StackBlitz (and locally) and was not able to reproduce the error message – consider providing a minimal amount of code that does. This could be a certain set of Tailwind utility classes that could be causing the error. Furthermore, you seem to have some PostCSS plugins in the Tailwind plugins section that shouldn't be there, namely postcss-import and tailwindcss/nesting. These should only be in postcss.config.js.

@Wongjn I found what caused the issue, I just don't know why this is happening, and I think that PostCss message is just a red hearing.

I replicated your updated code in a Stackblitz project but I was not able to reproduce any undesired behavior. It seems like something else could be causing the issue. However, I won't be able to help troubleshoot without code that reproduces the unexpected behavior. For the .before\:bg-warm-ivory dev+.before\:bg-warm-ivory div:before, :before rule applying everywhere, that could be a symptom of @apply abuse.
